# Dynamically add/remove xaxis categories in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am creating a polar spider chart and I'd like to know if it's possible to, dynamically, add/remove xaxis categories. 
Per example, let's say I have xaxis categories like [Banana, Apple, Pear, Grape] and instead of a legend with series, I would have a legend-like with the xaxis categories. When I would click on the Banana, the Banana category would disappear from the chart and when I click again it would re-appear. 
I read about xaxis setCategories but that implies defining a constant array which is not my purpose at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the highcharts you can use setCategories as you mentioned or call [axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update)